# Video JS Player with plugin videojs-preroll in Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, video.js

I successfully added the the code to wordpress header.php

```
<script src="video.js"></script>
<script src="videojs.ads.js"></script>
<script src="videojs-preroll.js"></script>
<link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="video.ads.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="videojs-preroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

all with correct paths adjusted

then in wordpress i created a post and switched to html editor

and added this code, without the code for the preroll

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="640"    height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
</video>
```

the video works perfect in wordpress!

but to fire up the preroll video i need to add this code

```
<script>
videojs('example_video_1', {plugins:{ads:{},preroll:{src:"advertisement.mp4"}}});
</script>
```

then it stops working

im sure i need to adjust the code for wordpress.

I got it all to work in regular html no problem

but client has wordpress and want to use it in wordpress post

I hope someone can help out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you putting that <script> tag? If you are using the content editor, that could be the issue. Try placing it manually in the footer. If that resolves it, consider using a shortcode to embed them in the content editor.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Wordpress is adding your script before the video element in the DOM. You could put the plugin settings in a `data-setup` attribute on the video element instead:

```
<video
  id="example_video_1"
  class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls
  width="640"
  height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"plugins":{"ads":{},"preroll":{"src":"advertisement.mp4"}}}'>
```

Note the use of single and double quotes - that's important.